# Filter for Text with spaces

Tags: ms-access, filtering

Using Microsoft Access I want to set a filter for records which include spaces. I tried double escaping by using `'""'` to no avail.

I have a table like so:

```
ID    Title
1     Green
2     Blue Yacht 
3     Yellow
```

and a form just displaying these records. When I now set the filter:

```
Form.Filter = "TestTable.Title LIKE '*Yellow*'"
```

it works like a charm. But when trying to filter for *"Blue Yacht"*

```
Form.Filter = "TestTable.Title LIKE '*Blue Yacht*'"
```

I get an empty result. Filtering for just *Blue* works like it is supposed to. Somehow Access doesn't like the spaces in the filter. How can I filter for e.g. *"Blue "* or *"Blue Yacht"*?

Comment: Are you sure you have a single space? That is a space and not a space-like character? Imports can contain these.

Comment: Yes it was a space. I actually found the problem elsewhere: somebody messed with the datasource which contained some other weird filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's very strange behaviour, it should work fine as is, you could try using the Chr code instead of the space:

```
Form.Filter = "TestTable.Title LIKE '*Blue" & Chr(32) & "Yacht*'"
```

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this old thread while searching a solution for the same problem. I found none so far. I wonder if this is a bug on Access or what.

So, this is my case, I tried both filters below. I was working to filter and populate a Datasheet subform. Filters are in Combo Box: Citrate, Paxgene, Sodium Herapin.

Dim sTType as string
    ...
    ...
1. sTType = "[Tube Type] LIKE '" & Me.txtTubeType & "*'"
2. sTType = "[Tube Type]  ='"    & Me.txtTubeType & "'"
   ...
   me.Filter = sTType

When Sodium Herapin is selected and applied as filter , the filter comes up with nothing, while I've no problem with the other word filters.

Sol.: I inserted this code way up

me.txtTubeType = iif(InStr(Trim(Me.txtTubeType), "Sod") > 0, "Sodium*", me.txtTubeType)

```
  ...
  ...
  sTType = "[Tube Type] LIKE '" & Me.txtTubeType & "'"
  me.Filter =  sTType
```

The work around is kind of crude but it worked for my situation.

Cheers!